# How to add <br> tags with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

So let's say I have

```
<p>Hello World</p>
```

Can BeautifulSoup add a 
 tag like so?

```
<br><p>Hello World</p>
```

Initially I could get around this by doing something like:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup("<p>Hello World<p>")
soup = BeautifulSoup(re.compile('(<p>)', '<br>\1', soup.prettify())
```

but the problem is that in actual usage with more complex html the .prettify() messes up the html by adding extra whitespace and lines.

I checked the docs but it doesn't even mention the

```
<br>
```

tag at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done using the [`soup.insert()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#insert) function

```
>>> br = soup.new_tag('br')
>>> br
<br/>
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup("<p>Hello World</p>")
>>> soup.insert(0,br)
>>> soup
<br/><p>Hello World</p>
```

The `insert()` function inserts a tag at any numeric position. Here we have specified as `0` so it is inserted at the start.