# How to combine two HTML files into one in Python

Tags: python, charts, merge

I created two plotly charts and saved them as HTML files separately. Is there a way to combine them into one HTML file? For example I can do this with PDF files using the following code:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader
merger = PdfFileMerger()

merger.append(PdfFileReader(open(filename1, 'rb')))
merger.append(PdfFileReader(open(filename2, 'rb')))

merger.write("merged.pdf")
```

Is there any library that can merge HTML files this way?

Comment: use a html-parser and merge the bodies of the files... of course you should ask yourself how do you want to merge them (header are the same?, "page" break?)

Comment: see for [ex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31175456/how-to-add-br-tags-with-beautifulsoup)

Comment: [PyPDF2 is deprecated. Use `pypdf`.](https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the python library `htmlmerger`
Ex:-

```
from htmlmerger import HtmlMerger
merger = HtmlMerger(input_directory="my_htmls/")  # result will be in my_htmls/merged.html
merger.merge(clean=True)  # or clean=False to keep the individual files (default behavior)
```